# Make one row out of number of rows in a query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables with a relationship of one to many.
After executing a query, I got the result table:

```
+-------+------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| index |       date       | sub_index | angle | length |
+-------+------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|   681 | 19/10/2016 15:49 |         1 |    30 |    333 |
|   681 | 19/10/2016 15:49 |         1 |    60 |    666 |
|   682 | 19/10/2016 15:52 |         2 |     0 |     44 |
|   682 | 19/10/2016 15:52 |         2 |    45 |     77 |
|   682 | 19/10/2016 15:52 |         2 |    90 |     67 |
+-------+------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

But the user asked for the information to be flat. Such as the following:

```
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| index |       date       | sub_index | angle1 | length1 | angle2 | length2 | angle3 | length3 |
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|   681 | 19/10/2016 15:49 |         1 |     30 |     333 |     60 |     666 |        |         |
|   682 | 19/10/2016 15:52 |         2 |      0 |      44 |     45 |      77 |     90 |      67 |
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

The number of angles and lengths is unknown and could be any number of items.

I read about a `PIVOT`, but I don't really know how to use it in this example, because of the changed columns (`angle1`, `angle2`...) and because I read that `PIVOT` need some function (`MAX`, `COUNT`, ...) and I need the value as is...

Comment: what you have tried to achieve it, let us know ?? use pivot to get your desired result

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  You're looking for something called a pivot query.  But if the number of angles could be variable, you might need dynamic SQL to handle this problem.

Comment: I could see `sub_index` column being messed up in the second table. Okay for you?

Comment: First we need data in textual format before join.From where angle and length are originating.Secondly can angle and length be more than 3.

Comment: I edited my question and made the data textual (hope it is OK like this).
Also, I added the comment that angle and length can be more than 3. It can be even 20... @KumarHarsh

Comment: How are you presenting this information?  This is generally a task best handled within your presentation layer.

Comment: I present the information in a DataGridView. @iamdave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you are missing one more attribute in you initial query.Let's call it Type. You can then use the bellow query to do what you want.

```
drop table if exists dbo.TableC;

create table dbo.TableC (
_Index int
, Date datetime
, Sub_index int
, Angle int
, Length int
, Type int
);


insert into dbo.TableC (_Index, Date, Sub_index, Angle, Length, Type)
values (681, CONVERT(datetime, '19/10/2016 15:49', 103), 1, 30, 333, 1)
, (681, CONVERT(datetime, '19/10/2016 15:49', 103), 1, 60, 666, 2)
, (682, CONVERT(datetime, '19/10/2016 15:52', 103), 2, 0, 44, 1)
, (682, CONVERT(datetime, '19/10/2016 15:52', 103), 2, 45, 77, 2)
, (682, CONVERT(datetime, '19/10/2016 15:52', 103), 2, 90, 67, 3)



select
    t._Index, t.Date, t.Sub_index
    , max(case when t.Type = 1 then t.Angle else null end) as Angle1
    , max(case when t.Type = 1 then t.Length else null end) as Length1
    , max(case when t.Type = 2 then t.Angle else null end) as Angle2
    , max(case when t.Type = 2 then t.Length else null end) as Length2
    , max(case when t.Type = 3 then t.Angle else null end) as Angle3
    , max(case when t.Type = 3 then t.Length else null end) as Length3
from dbo.TableC t
group by t._Index, t.Date, t.Sub_index
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible dynamic solution. Please note that the number of columns in the resulting table depends from the input data, which is usually a bad idea. For this reason it will be tricky to put this code inside a stored procedure.

Nonetheless here is a TSQL fragment that should answer your question:

```
--create a custom type that will be used in the final dynamic call
if exists (select * from sys.types where name = 'TestTableType')
    drop type TestTableType
create type TestTableType as table([index] int,[sub_index] int, [data] nvarchar(max))

go

--this table contains your input data
declare @tem table([index] int, [date] datetime , [sub_index] int, [angle] decimal (19,6),[length] decimal (19,6))
--temp table used to calculate maximum number of columns to show
declare @counters table([index] int,[sub_index] int, [counter] int)
--temp table that will hold denormalized values (one row for each index/subindex couple)
declare @denormalized_data TestTableType
--this variables contains the maximum number of columns to show
declare @max_columns int
--this variable will contain the dunamically generated TSQL query that will give the final result
declare @dynamic_query nvarchar(max) 
--support variables used to generate dynamic query
declare @counter int 
declare @counter_str nvarchar(max) 

--1. populate input data
insert into @tem select  681 , '20161019 15:49',  1 ,   30,    333 
insert into @tem select  681 , '20161019 15:49',  1 ,   60,    666 
insert into @tem select  682 , '20161019 15:52',  2 ,    0,    44 
insert into @tem select  682 , '20161019 15:52',  2 ,    45,   77 
insert into @tem select  682 , '20161019 15:52',  2 ,    90,   67 
--insert into @tem select  682 , '20161019 15:52',  2 ,    8,    88 

--2. calculate the number of columns to show
insert into @counters
select [index],[sub_index], COUNT(*) from @tem group by [index],[sub_index]

select @max_columns =  max([counter]) from @counters

--3. denormalize data using an XML-based approach to obtain one row for each index/subindex couple
insert into @denormalized_data
SELECT 
  [index],[sub_index],
 '<MyData>'+ STUFF((
    SELECT '  <angle>' +  CAST([angle] AS VARCHAR(MAX))  + '</angle><length>' + CAST([length] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +'</length>'
    FROM @tem 
    WHERE ([index] = Results.[index] and [sub_index] = Results.[sub_index]) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') +  '</MyData>' AS NameValues
FROM @tem Results
GROUP BY [index],[sub_index]

--4. generate a dynamic TSQL query with the correct number of columns
set @counter = 0
set @dynamic_query=' SELECT [index],[sub_index],   '
while       @counter < @max_columns
  begin
     set @counter = @counter +1
     set @counter_str =  CAST(@counter  as nvarchar(max))
     set @dynamic_query = @dynamic_query + ' CONVERT(XML,[data]).value(''/MyData[1]/angle['+  @counter_str + ']'',''varchar(100)'') AS angle'+  @counter_str + ',  '
     set @dynamic_query = @dynamic_query + ' CONVERT(XML,[data]).value(''/MyData[1]/length['+  @counter_str + ']'',''varchar(100)'') AS length'+  @counter_str + ',  '
  end

set @dynamic_query = substring(@dynamic_query,1,LEN(@dynamic_query) - 1) + ' FROM @denormalized_d ' 

exec sp_executesql @dynamic_query, N'@denormalized_d TestTableType readonly', @denormalized_data
```

Here is the output with 3 distinct values:

[image]

Here is the output with 4 distinct values (just uncomment the line `--insert into @tem select  682 , '20161019 15:52',  2 ,    8,    88` ):

[image]